# i want to display 0 as 0.00 in php. NumberFormatter() is not working for that

Tags: php

i want to display 0 as 0.00 in php. NumberFormatter() is not working for that

Answer (score 3):

It is not

```
NumberFormatter()
```

use

```
 number_format($variable,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$var = 0;
echo $outVar = sprintf('%0.2f', $var); //0.00
```